# Working with SSE (Server-Sent Events) in a corporate environment

Tags: iis, port, server-sent-events, restriction

Is it possible to offer SSE (Server-Sent Events) on port 80, the same port that users use to access a web application?

Opening non standard ports in Corporate environments is HELL.

How do we offer a web application on port 80, and also stream Server-Sent Events to the same port?

My current solution is an in-house web application that uses Server-Sent Events on port 9000 to push dashboard updates.

**Edit: More Details**

In my solution the real-time data is not being severed from IIS.

I have a console app that receives and processes external real-time events then pushes those to a url on port 9000. The console Application uses a httpListener to server the server-sent events.

The IIS application points to the event-source from that console app to display live statistics to the web applications users.

This requires IT Security to allow traffic on the *non-standard* port **9000** for the set of users who need to access the web application.

Please what alternatives would you suggest?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Absolutely. Server-sent Events are just standard HTTP, so you'll be on port 80 by default.

What makes you think that you need to serve them on a nonstandard port?

Comment: in my solution the real time data is not being severed from IIS. I have a console app that receives and processes external real-time events then pushes those to a url on port 9000. the IIS application points to the event-source from that console to display live statistics to the web applications users

Comment: Why can't that be on port 80? Is it the same machine as IIS?

Comment: Why are you doing this with a console app?

Comment: Yes it is the same machine as IIS

Comment: The core application that processes the external data sources is an always on system, it involves connecting to some external TCP -socket based services that cannot be conveniently hosted in IIS. hence i use a console to do all that. the results of that processing, i make available to a dashboard via SSE on port 9000. it cannot be port 80 since IIS on the same machine has port 80

Comment: I can think of a few options. Host the console app on a different machine, install a certificate on the console app and serve it via https (port 443), or work out to do this via IIS.

Comment: Question: How do you serve a continuous data stream from IIS? polling from a database? IIS really doesn't lend itself to this sort of thing.

Comment: Charles. That is a different question. I suggest you repost.

Comment: I guess so. but it still leaves me with this post unsolved.